# How to implement (sort-of) templated virtual function calls in C++

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I need to implement a class structure with a virtual function template for a fixed set of types as template argument (there is only one template parameter). This is to my knowledge not directly possible in C++, since there is no way to tell the compiler for which template arguments it should reserve entries in the vtable.

I found a pattern based on boost::fusion which seems to implement the right behaviour, but I am wondering if this can be generalised further, preferably without relying heavily on macros.

First, here is the code to start with:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/fusion/include/at_key.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

template< template<typename> class Signature >
class TemplateVTable {
  public:
    boost::fusion::map<
        boost::fusion::pair<int, Signature<int> >,
        boost::fusion::pair<double, Signature<double> >
     > table;
};

class A {
  public:
    template<typename UserType>
    UserType doSomething(UserType arg) {
        return boost::fusion::at_key<UserType>(myVTable.table)(arg);
    }

    template<typename UserType>
    class functionSignature : public boost::function< UserType(UserType) > {
      public:
        boost::function< UserType(UserType) >& operator=(const boost::function< UserType(UserType) > &rhs) {
          return boost::function< UserType(UserType) >::operator=(rhs);
        }
    };

    TemplateVTable< functionSignature > myVTable;
};


class B : public A {
  public:

    class FillVTable {
      public:
        FillVTable(B *_object) : object(_object) {}

        template<typename T>
        void operator()(T& pair) const {
          pair.second = boost::bind(&B::doSomething<typename T::first_type>, object, _1);
        }

    private:

        B *object;
    };

    B() {
      boost::fusion::for_each(myVTable.table, FillVTable(this));
    }

    template<typename UserType>
    UserType doSomething(UserType arg) {
        return arg+offset;
    }

    int offset;

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {   
    B b;
    b.offset = 3;

    A *a = &b;

    std::cout << a->doSomething<int>(5.3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << a->doSomething<double>(5.3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles fine with gcc 4.6.3 and outputs as expected:

```
8
8.3
```

Just to explain how it works: The boost::fusion::map is filled by the derived class upon construction with pointers to its templated member function "doSomething" for all types in the map (see the for_each statement and the FillVTable functor class). In the base class, the templated member function "doSomthing" extracts the right pointer for the template parameter from the map and calls the implementation in the derived class.

Now here are my questions how to make this pattern more general and maybe shorter:

1. When instantiating the TemplateVTable<> in the base class (member declaration of A::myVTable) I need to use a trick to pass the `boost::function< UserType(UserType) >` template parameter. The problem is that the template parameter itself is a template. Is there a way to do this directly without defining an extra class "functionSignature"? I tried something like this:

   ```
   TemplateVTable< template<UserType> boost::function< UserType(UserType) > > myVTable;
   ```

   but it doesn't compile (invalid template argument).
2. To make it more general, I would like to generate the class TemplateVTable somehow from a given list of types, e.g. in form of template arguments or as a mpl::vector or so. Is this somehow possible? I could imagine using some cascaded macros to do this for a limited number of types, but using e.g. a variadic template argument would be nicer as it would not limit the number of types.
3. Is it somehow possible to replace the functor class FillVTable with a lambda expression? It would have to be a templated lambda expression, but I cannot find anything about this in the documentation.
4. Could we extend this for more than one template parameter?

I am using gcc 4.3.6 on Ubuntu 12.04 with -std=c++0x enabled to have (incomplete) C++11 support. Unfortunately I have to stick with that old compiler still for a while...

Comment: Try to limit yourself to 1 question per question. Otherwise a really good first question.

Comment: This belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)